# I am not able to parse the string in java to long

Tags: java, servlets

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Transactions trans=new Transactions();

        System.out.println(request.getParameter("assetid"));
        System.out.println(request.getParameter("barcodeno"));
        System.out.println(request.getParameter("location"));
        System.out.println(request.getParameter("employeeid"));
        System.out.println(request.getParameter("categoryid"));


        String categoryId=request.getParameter("categoryid");
        String employeeId=request.getParameter("employeeid");
        String Assetid=request.getParameter("assetid");
        String locationcode=request.getParameter("locationcode");

        long  AssetId=Long.parseLong(Assetid);
        long  categoryid123=Long.parseLong(categoryId);
        long  employeeid=Long.parseLong(employeeId);
        long  LocationCode=Long.parseLong(locationcode);

        System.out.println("here the employeeId id is"+employeeId);
        System.out.println("here the Assetid id is"+Assetid);



        trans.setBarcodeno(request.getParameter("barcodeno"));
        trans.setLocation(new LocationMaster(LocationCode));
        trans.setAssetId(AssetId);

        trans.setCategory(new CategoryMaster((categoryid123)));
        trans.setEmployee(new EmployeeMaster(employeeid));
        //trans.setEquipment(new EquipmentMaster(employeeid));

        SessionFactory sessionFactory=HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
        Session sessionHb=sessionFactory.openSession();

        Transaction tx=sessionHb.beginTransaction();

        HttpSession session=request.getSession();
        sessionHb.save(trans);
        System.out.println("transition saved");
        tx.commit();
        response.sendRedirect("Assetisued.jsp");
        //CategoryMaster categorymaster =;

        }
```

The following are the values which i get from before parsing

```
Asset id=101
Categoryid=1
Barcode =1
Employeeid=10
locationid=1
```

Dear sir i am not able to parse the string values into long as it is giving `NumberFormatException`. I am able to get all string values as shown. I checked everything but unable to understand what exactly the problem is. Please check it and give me your feedback...

Comment: Just as a tip, don't have variables named `Assetid` and `AssetId`. Having names that close means you *will* mix them up at some point.

Answer (score 1):

First, store these parameters' value into varibles, then print the variables' value and what will hanppen.

e.g:

```
String categoryId=request.getParameter("categoryid");
System.out.println(categoryId);
long  categoryid123=Long.parseLong(categoryId);
```

See whether could occur NumberFormatException.

Answer (score 0):

There is probably whitespace in your input.

Try removing whitespace, eh:

```
long AssetId=Long.parseLong(Assetid.trim());
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be more a problem in how you find problems than the actual error.

To make it easier to find problems, make sure you follow the naming conventions
i.e. Variables should be in camel casing

```
long  locationCode=Long.parseLong(locationcode);
```

not

```
long  LocationCode=Long.parseLong(locationcode);
```

The second thing I would suggest is to make your variable names more descriptible and distinct.
A good rule for this is: "If the only difference between variables is the casing, they are too similar."

For more info on this visit http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html

Lastly, if you're facing a problem and you're asking a quetion about it, you should find the minimal amount of code that still produces the problem. This way, it's easier to help you, so people will be more inclined to.

Now for the actual problem, I think you need to make sure you're not parsing too many spaces.
i.e.
In

```
Barcode =1
```

You should remove the space so that it becomes

```
Barcode=1
```

And in

```
Asset id=101
```

I think the space is causing some problems too.

I'm sorry I didn't get to fix your problem but I hope this helped anyway.